# Is there any PERIOD datatype for SAS sql ?

Tags: sas

I have the following table for people running a marathon

```
person  start       end
mike    2-Jun-14    2-Aug-14
nike    3-Jul-14    9-Aug-14
mini    1-Aug-14    3-Nov-14
```

I want to know if a person was "running the marathon" on the 1st of each month. The desired table should look like this

```
person  running on
mike    1-Jul-14
mike    1-Aug-14
nike    1-Aug-14
mini    1-Aug-14 
mini    1-Sep-14
... for all other months
```

Is there any way in SAS `proc sql` to get this result. The other dbms have this (Teradata, Oracle). What is the best approach to this in SAS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a DATA STEP to solve this in SAS.

```
data have;
input person $ from :anydtdte. to :anydtdte.;
format from to date11.;
datalines;
mike    2-Jun-14    2-Aug-14
nike    3-Jul-14    9-Aug-14
mini    1-Aug-14    3-Nov-14
;
run;

data want(keep=person running_on);
set have;
format Running_on date11.;

do Running_on=from to to;
    if day(running_on) = 1 then
        output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: You might consider using the `intnx` function to move directly to the next month rather than iterating over every day.

Comment: I was thinking more of a `proc sql` solution. The above solution uses external (NON SQL) superpowers. Well, if SAS sql is not good enough for this, then this solution is accepted